# How to disable inbuilt speakers while using earphones?

Tags: audio, windows-11

The earphones are using a cord on the jack at the front. To get it work I had to disable autodetect. Autodetect was only working on the mic jack.
But now sound comes out of the inbuilt speaker and through the speakers. Its Realtek. How to disable inbuilt speakers on Win 11?

Comment: Is that the only headphone jack or is there a true headphone that supports auto connect? My Lenovo headphone jack disconnects the internal speakers

Answer (score -1):

Usually a pluged in earphone would disable the speakers automatically. I don't know if you encountered a hardware issue or a software issue, but you can try [Voicemeeter](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/index.htm) to route audio to only your earphones. Note that using Voicemeeter adds a bit of audio latency.